# Android singleTap/OnClick in WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

i am loading Web view with Html String,i want to show navigate buttons when the user tap on the web view,i tried With onTouch listener,touch event raises when scrolling and tapping but 
**i want to catch single tap/clickEvent, Not scroll Event touches..., i implemented SetOnClickListener for both WebView and LinearLayout,None of them is not working for me**
Any help regarding this

Answer (score 24):

`WebView` does not support the `OnClickListener`. And also it does consume touch events even though nothing happened on the web page thus ancestors views (like your `LinearLayout`) don't have any chance to produce an OnClick event. It is very unfortunate.

As a workaround I extended a `RelativeLayout` and put my `WebView` inside of it. In the `RelativeLayout` I've overwritten `onInterceptTouchEvent` and were looking for tap events. If a tap is detected then the `RelativeLayout`'s `OnClickListener` is invoked with `performClick()`.

```
public class TapAwareRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    private final float MOVE_THRESHOLD_DP = 20 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    private boolean mMoveOccured;
    private float mDownPosX;
    private float mDownPosY;

public TapAwareRelativeLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public TapAwareRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    final int action = ev.getAction();
    switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        mMoveOccured = false;
        mDownPosX = ev.getX();
        mDownPosY = ev.getY();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        if (!mMoveOccured) {
            // TAP occured
            performClick();
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if (Math.abs(ev.getX() - mDownPosX) > MOVE_THRESHOLD_DP || Math.abs(ev.getY() - mDownPosY) > MOVE_THRESHOLD_DP) {
            mMoveOccured = true;
        }
        break;

    }
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

}

Comment: @Zsolt - I did not get how to put webView in RelativeLayout, could u please give more info on this?

Comment: You put the WebView into the RelativeLayout in the xml layout file. The size u specified for the WebView before is now the size specification of the RelativeLayout and u make the WebView just match the size of its parent (the RelativeLayout). This will make them have the same size while the RelativeLayout wraps the WebView.

Answer (score 3):

I modified Zsolt Safrany's answer and I put his `onInterceptTouchEvent`'s content into webview's `onTouch` method and it worked.

```
webview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    Log.v(TAG,"Got a touch event in the web view!");

    final int action = ev.getAction();
    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
           mMoveOccured = false;
           mDownPosX = ev.getX();
           mDownPosY = ev.getY();
       break;
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
           if (!mMoveOccured) {
             //click operation is here
           }
      break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
          if (Math.abs(ev.getX() - mDownPosX) > MOVE_THRESHOLD_DP || Math.abs(ev.getY() - mDownPosY) > MOVE_THRESHOLD_DP) {
          mMoveOccured = true;
      }
      break;
}
    return false;
}           });
```

Comment: This solution contains mistakes (event and ev.getX()) and works as the first solution, i.e. doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

From this page: http://www.codeshogun.com/blog/2009/04/16/how-to-implement-swipe-action-in-android/

It seems that touch events must be properly trapped.  Check this out:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e){
    super.dispatchTouchEvent(e);
    return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked code ::

```
final Boolean[] mMoveOccured = new Boolean[1];
final float[] mDownPosX = new float[1];
final float[] mDownPosY = new float[1];

final float MOVE_THRESHOLD_DP = 20 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

userPic.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
           final int action = event.getAction();
           switch (action) {
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    mMoveOccured[0] = false;
                    mDownPosX[0] = event.getX();
                    mDownPosY[0] = event.getY();
                    break;
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (!mMoveOccured[0]) {
                       Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Webview pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (Math.abs(event.getX() - mDownPosX[0]) > MOVE_THRESHOLD_DP || Math.abs(event.getY() - mDownPosY[0]) > MOVE_THRESHOLD_DP) {
                            mMoveOccured[0] = true;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return false;
      }
 });
```