# Get javascript callback from webview

Tags: javascript, android

I'm trying to get a json data and a callback from javascript using webview.
I can get the json data but the problem is I cannot get the callback.

I need to fire the callback after a condition is met.

Android Code:

```
--------
// Adding the interface
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "code");
--------
@JavascriptInterface
        public void execute(String JsonData, String callback) {
            String d = data; <---HAS JSON DATA RETURNED TO ANDROID
            Log.d("jSon Data", d);
            mCallback = callback; <---RETURNS "undefined"
        }
```

Javascript code (I can't edit this.):

```
 code.execute(JsonData, function(callback){
                    console.log(callback);
});
```

Android on button click

```
@OnClick(R.id.callback)
    void onButtonCallback() {
        String s = "Hello World";
//       pass Hello World back to javascript. But I'm getting "undefined" 
//       for the callback
        mCallback.passdata(s);
    }
```

What I'm trying to achieve is:

1) Get data from Javascript to Android -> OKAY

2) Get the Callback from Javascript to Android -> Here's my problem

3) Fire the callback along with "hello world" string on button click

Note: I can't edit the javascript code. How am I going to achieve this? Do I need to inject Js from Android? If yes, how?

I just need to solve item number 2 to move forward. Thanks!

Comment: I suspect that you are looking for something else. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116909/how-can-i-get-onclick-event-on-webview-in-android or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907194/android-singletap-onclick-in-webview/9065581#9065581 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116909/how-can-i-get-onclick-event-on-webview-in-android

Comment: Noo, @Nico, the callback will fire onClick. I'm not trying to get onclick event on webview.

Comment: Ohh, it's true, sorry about my comment. I now can see that you want is to pass the function instance to java then call it. But is not the way that this work. AFAIK, addJavascriptInterface() only works with primitive types and Strings, and so you cannot pass arbitrary Javascript objects (like functions).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. At least, based on my tests `addJavascriptInterface()` only works with primitive types and Strings, and so you cannot pass Javascript objects like functions.

Comment: Okay, so do you have any idea on how to set this up to achieve my goal? What are the adjustments for js and android side?

Comment: The only way that I can imagine is modifying your JS but you said that this is not possible. I you can do that then you can implement something like a strategy pattern in the JS side to take messages like `doSomething` and execute what you want. I hope to be helpful with you.