# When should one use android:clickable?

Tags: android, clickable

When should we use `android:clickable` in XML? Should we ever?
Is there any difference between such XML declaration and in-code declaration `myButton.setOnClickListener`? I have read the documentation, but I could not find out when and why should I ever use this attribute.

PS. I was implementing an ad SDK and found that their developers were using `android:clickable` with `WebView` and I was intrigued why did they use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the documentation states, and as far as I know :

> `clickable` - Defines whether this view reacts to click events.
>   Must be a boolean value, either "true" or "false".

So for example if you just declare a `Webview` or `View` in your `layout.xml` and try to set an `OnClickListener` on this views the `OnClick` event won't be fired unless you specify the attribute :

```
  android:clickable=true
```

Comment: I am confused. If I have a Button or any other View, I never use this value and I can implement onClickListener thou. I think I did not get what you said.

Comment: yes the button is by default clickable. but for instance ImageView I think it is not by default clickable.

Comment: setOnClickListener makes the View clickable:
[docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener))

Comment: @FunkTheMonk Thanks. Now back to my question: Why and when would I use `android:clickable` if I can just implement `onClickListener`?

Comment: @bergnam instead of onClickListener(this); (on an activity that implements OnClickListener) you could put onClick="onClick" and have the same method prototype [public void onClick(View v)] that doesn't require your activity to implement OnClickListener. Why? for shiz & giggles.

You can set clickable=false when you don't want to make the view enabled=false, but you don't want to un-assign/reassign the onClickListener either. You might want a view to have a different draw state when clicked, but not do anything.

Setting both clickable=true and setOnClickListener is redundant. Both have uses.

Comment: you should put this in an answer I think

Comment: old QA, but its worth to note that `WebView` isn't a proper extension of `View` for an example, because [we can't set (easily)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116909/how-can-i-get-onclick-event-on-webview-in-android) `OnClickListener' :) all other works as far as I know

Answer (score 11):

`clickable` seems to be useful when you need a view to consume clicks so that they do not go to views beneath the top view.

For example, I have a `FrameLayout` that I display over an underlying `RelativeLayout` at certain times.  When the user would click on an underlying `EditText` the focus would shift to that `EditText`.  Really annoying when the `FrameLayout` was still being shown.  Now the user doesn't know why a keyboard just popped up or where they are typing.

When I set `clickable="true"` in the `FrameLayout`, users could no longer accidentally click underlying `EditText` fields.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    ...>
    <EditText>
    <EditText>
    <EditText>
    <!-- FrameLayout with grayed-out background. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/sometimes_visible_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#80808080"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:focusable="true"
        ...>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            ...>
            <View>
            <View>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are setting `view.setOnClickListener` on any `View`,
eg: `myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener)` by default it is considered 
as `clickable="true"`.

So you would not need to mention that in the XML file like 
`android:clickable="true"`. The `onClick()` event will be fired without using
`android:clickable="true"`.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced a situation, where I had made an activity swipeable (swipe left/right or right/left to move forward/backwards). In some screens there were places that was only filled out with a LinearLayout. There was no `OnClickListener` for the layout (it wasn't needed) causing the swipe action not to be registered when performed on the `LinearLayout`. Setting the `android:clickable="true"` solved the problem.

To answer your questions and as the above shows, there are situations in which using the `clickable`-attribute can be usefull.

I don't believe you can say that setting an `OnClickListener` is the same as setting the `clickable`-attribute, but setting the `OnClickListener` certainly makes the `View` clickable, making the `clickable`-attribute useless (in that particular situation).

Comment: If you make `LinearLayout` clickable and it has child elements, how will Android distinguish if I want to fire element's `onClick` or layout's `onClick`? Will it work like this: if I touch element, then its `onClick` will be fired, if I click on empty space (inside of layour), then LinearLayout's `onClick` will be fired?

Comment: Yes, that's what would happen. All though in my above example there was no `onClick`-event registered for the `LinearLayout` - I just needed it to register clicks in order for them to be passed to my swipe functionality.

Answer (score 1):

FYI; When you use the `android:onClick=""` attribute or call `setOnClickListener(...)` programmatically, the View class sets the `clickable` flag to `true`.

```
/**
 * Register a callback to be invoked when this view is clicked. If this view is not
 * clickable, it becomes clickable.
 *
 * @param l The callback that will run
 *
 * @see #setClickable(boolean)
 */
public void setOnClickListener(@Nullable OnClickListener l) {
    if (!isClickable()) {
        setClickable(true);
    }
    getListenerInfo().mOnClickListener = l;
}
```

As to when you should set the clickable flag yourself, I think mostly when you want a View to *not* be cickable, e.g. to stop repeated calls while some data is loading, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why did they use in that case, but, I had to use it when I created a class, which was extending linearLayout.

I created my own "control", and I wanted it clickable, so I had to use it.

This is one scenario when you will use it