# android:clickable="True" breaks clickability of cardviews

Tags: android

I have cardviews that I dynamically add at runtime to a `LinearLayout` (which is inside a `NestedScrollView`). I set each cardview to have an `onClickListener()`. When I set `android:clickable="true"` under each cardview (I want the ripple animation when the user clicks the cardview), the `onClickListener` only responds if I tap the margin area (15dp) above the cardview. It doesn't respond if I click the actual cardview.

When I set `android:clickable="false"` the `onClickListener` works as intended, responding to a press inside the cardview.

How can I get it so that the "click box" (for lack of a better phrase) is the cardview when clickable is set to true, and not the margin below it? Note that I am using the relatively new Material 3 components.

Here's the cardview xml

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:id="@+id/routeCardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/Cardview"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    style="?attr/materialCardViewFilledStyle">

    <TextView
        style="@style/cardview_header"
        android:id="@+id/routeName"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="Test Text" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/cardview_body"
        android:id="@+id/cruise_description"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="test text" />

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

And here's the Java code where I actually set the on click listeners, and add the cardviews to the linear layout

```
            if (allRoutes != null){ 
                ArrayList<RouteCardView> routeCardViews = new ArrayList<>();

                for (UserRoute ur : allRoutes){ 
                    RouteCardView cardView = new RouteCardView(this, ur);
                    routeCardViews.add(cardView);

                    //for each RouteCardView, set an onClickListener
                    cardView.getView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            startNavigation(cardView.getRoute());
                        }
                    });
                }

                Collections.sort(routeCardViews, new RouteCardViewComparator());

                for (RouteCardView rcv : routeCardViews){
                    savedCruisesLinearLayout.addView(rcv.getView());
                }
```

Comment: First of all, why you implement setOnClick event when you already define clickable in XML ? That have same function so you dont need initialize again

Comment: check this for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817608/when-should-one-use-androidclickable