# android: set WebView to (real) full screen

Tags: android, webview, fullscreen

I'm trying to make my `WebView` `fullscreen` by standard, i know how to stretch it to "full screen" but what I'm trying to do is to create the full screen you get when you long click the `WebView` and choose the full screen option.
does anyone knows how to do that ?

edit: What I mean is how to enter "Full Screen Mode" which is in option in `WebView` when you long click it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to hide status bar and title bar use below code

in java file

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

in manifest file

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

or if you want to resize the webview according to your actions use below code in your action listener

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    webview.setLayoutParams(params);
```

try the above, it may help you.

Comment: I Don't mean this kind of full screen, but thanks anyway.
Read my edit maybe you can understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change height and width of web view programmatically to fill parent.i think you can change it by onclick listener of web view. for reference  [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116909/how-i-get-event-onclick-on-webview-in-android)