# Android: WebView onClick not work?

Tags: android, android-layout, webview, android-ndk, android-webview

I going to hide and show the Layout onclick of the webview.

I have code like below:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.backButton:
        finish();
        break;
    case R.id.webView:
        if(bottomShow){
            bottomLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bottomShow = false;
        }
        else{
            bottomLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bottomShow = true;
        }

        break;
    }
}
```

I have also set the clickListener as like

```
webView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

but even after doing that i am not getting any effect.

Why i am not able to get action on click on the webview ??

After Somehelp i have try it onTouchListener like below:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.webView:
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(bottomShow){
                    bottomLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    bottomShow = false;
                }
                else{
                    bottomLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    bottomShow = true;
                }
                return true;
            }

            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now it works but webView is not smoothly scrolling as it does before.

So whats the proper solution for that ? or whats wrong in my code if it is ??

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Try this post .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116909/how-i-get-event-onclick-on-webview-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with OnTouchListener of Webview