# How to overriding webviews ontouch method

Tags: android, webview

All I want to do whenever the event is touched is to direct the user to a page.

So what I have are two webviews. A banner and another webview above it. I want to cause the banner webview to open a browser with a link that I will give it , or start another activity with another webview,..doesnt matter.. But what I want to know, is how to catch the ontouch event of the webview..here is my webview so far:

```
        banner = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.banner);
        domainUrl = bannerUrl;

    android_id = Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    banner.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    banner.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    banner.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    banner.clearHistory();
    banner.clearFormData();
    banner.clearCache(true);
    webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    banner.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webViewClient = new MyWebViewClient();
    banner.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
    banner.loadUrl(domainUrl);
```

I thought to add this code:

```
    banner.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //How to open a browser here?
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I think this [link][1] solve your problem


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116909/how-i-can-get-onclick-event-on-webview-in-android

Comment: I looked at it.. and it isnt useful. I think my code should work..I am trying to switch to another activity on Touch event..should work..return true...should prevent default..shouldnt it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 banner.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //How to open a browser here?
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(domainUrl));
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```