# Detect Click on WebView in ANDROID with HTML data

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, onclick

I am trying to find whether a user clicks a webview in android.
The WebView Contains some html/javascript that loads. I want to find whether the user clicks the webview.

thanks for the help.

the code is something like this:

//....//

```
    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    wv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    String html = "<html><body style='margin:0;padding:0;'><script='text/javascript' src='URL'></script></body></html>";

    wv.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

//....//

thanks for the help....

Comment: Take a look at this thread:

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116909/how-i-can-get-onclick-event-on-webview-in-android

Comment: i want the javascript interface solution preferably ..anyways thanx...

Answer (score 0):

Create handler in your android application like

```
wv.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptHandler(this),"MyHandler");
```

And in your HTML using action listener callback method with your android handler then you can monitor your webview activities from android [Similar Example Here](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2012/03/16/android-development-javascript-bridge-example-fully-explained/)