# Browsing a site using webView in ANdroid

Tags: android, webview

I have loaded a website with my `WebView`. But when I click in any link of that website , the control has been transferred from my `WebView` to the Android built in browser. I want to browse that site with my `WebView`.

I want to download book from my site. Another task that is very important to me is when I will download a book from my site ,it will give a password to my software ( android part ). What do I do to receive a password from an web site from the `WebView`.

This question is very important for me to complete my project. 
Waiting for your replies...

The code for webView is just as following:

```
wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainwebview);
WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
ws.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
wv.loadUrl("http://m.feedbooks.com/store");
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: This thread may help you:
[How I can get onclick event on webview in android?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116909/how-i-can-get-onclick-event-on-webview-in-android

Comment: Another task that is very important to me is when I will download a book from my site ,it will give a password to my software ( android part ). What do I do to receive a password from an web site from the software ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,String url) {
                        view.loadUrl(url);
                        return true;
                    }

                });
                wv.loadUrl(url);
```

above code can help you to display website with your webview

Comment: Another task that is very important to me is when I will download a book from my site ,it will give a password to my software ( android part ). What do I do to receive a password from an web site from the software ??

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the WebViewClient[1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29)

You can override shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)

Comment: Another task that is very important to me is when I will download a book from my site ,it will give a password to my software ( android part ). What do I do to receive a password from an web site from the software ??