# Android View Not Receiving Touches

Tags: android, touch, android-webview, unity-game-engine

I'm added a Webview to an (UnityPlayer) Activity but the webview is not receiving touches.

I cant add the webview to a new Activity due to the loading times. So im currently fetching the root view from the current activity and adding a new layout that contains a webview. Obviously something in the application is stopping my webview from accepting touches. Any ideas how to make sure the webview accepts touches.

```
UnityPlayer.currentActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
        FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(UnityPlayer.currentActivity); 
        WebView webview = new WebView(UnityPlayer.currentActivity); 
        webview.loadUrl(url);
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup)(UnityPlayer.currentActivity.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content));
        rootView.addView(layout);
        layout.addView(webview);
   }
});
```

Please note: I do not have access to UntiyPlayer.currentActivity source

Cheers Everyone

Comment: possible duplicate of [How I can get onclick event on webview in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116909/how-i-can-get-onclick-event-on-webview-in-android)

Comment: No its a different issue. If i create a new activity and add the webview to that activity than the webview accepts touches without an issue. However, if i add the webview to the UnityPlayer.currentActivity then something in that activity stops the webview from accepting touches. So the issue isn't with the webview, its got to do with the view that stopping the touches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to add

```
<meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
```

To the activity in the manefest

Comment: Can you please provide more details?  I use plugin https://github.com/gree/unity-webview  .  AndroidManifest in its sample code has <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" /> ,   but on this site https://minecraft.net/login I cannot do any input in textfields.