# How to setOnclick Listener to a WebView which is inside a ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-viewpager, onclicklistener

I have a `ViewPager` which contains several `WebViews`. I wanted to set a `OnClickListener` to the `WebView`. I know that `WebView` consumes the touch but to overcome this I got a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5125620/2637715) and its working also but the problem is when I use the same piece of code inside the `ViewPager WebView`, it doesn't work. Can anyone suggest me how to achieve this? Any help will be highly appreciated.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have overridden the following method to solve the problem and it worked for me,

```
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        if(ev.getPointerCount() == 1)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "...3....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return true;

    }
```

Hope it helps. Cheers!!

Comment: Well it works to some extent.This method is showing that Toast message so many times even if I touch once also.

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same problem.but i overcome this by using ImageView.
  this is my Webview page xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradientbg"
    android:paddingBottom="3dip"
    android:paddingLeft="3dip"
    android:paddingRight="3dip"
    android:paddingTop="3dip" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >



        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:scrollbars="none" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

then i write this code in my adapter class

```
public Object instantiateItem(View container, final int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mywebview, null);
    WebView wv = (WebView) layout.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    ImageView im=(ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    im.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //    myPosition(position);

          //write you task here...
        }
    });
    }
```

all the best. this solution will compulsory work for you.

Comment: As you can see my WebView is a ViewPager item, will ViewPager swipe work this way?

Comment: yes @Ram i do the same this.

Comment: :Your solution works fine for horizontal scrolling but the problem is webview vertical scroll will not work this way.

Comment: we are just set the imageview on the webview. why its not working for vertical scroll?try to fix the imageview on webview @Ram

Comment: Dude its because the `ImageView` is consuming the focus.Do you got any trick to overcome this?