# Javascript function working in desktop browser but not in android webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

thanks for the time dedicated trying to help.

I have a simply javascript function that works in all browsers, however when i run in an android Webview environment, the function doesn't work.

My Function:

```
    function toggleList() {
         var ArrLinks = new Array();
         var iconID = document.getElementById('header_toggle');
         ArrLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for(var i=0; i<ArrLinks.length;i++)
    {
        if (ArrLinks[i] != null) {
            if (ArrLinks[i].getAttribute("data-id") == null){
                ArrLinks[i].click();
            }
        }
    }
   }
```

Any idea why this function wouldn't work on webView ? The function is called by onclick() on a button and it simply clicks on all li elements that do not have a data-id set.

I thought important to note that other javascript functions work correctly.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by calling the onclick function rather than click(). Working great for both browser and android

Answer (score 0):

Android WebView does not recognize a click event. Consider using a touch event (take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_events_touch.asp) for more information about jquery mobile)

Comment: If you know how to control the WebView you may consider this discussion useful too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116909/how-i-can-get-onclick-event-on-webview-in-android

Comment: so is there a tap() alternative that works both ways ? Its important that the same code works on both desktop browsers and android so i can't have different versions

Comment: Solved by calling onclick instead of click function.