# OnClick on webview in android?

Tags: java, android, events, webview, click

I want get the Onclick event on webView like that :

```
    webView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: Okay. Good. What's the problem?

Comment: That's good! What next?

Comment: the problem is that webView not listening to the click event

Comment: it accepts only the longClick

Answer (score 1):

Your code blocks click for item on page on web view, but you can use onTouchListener

```
mWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                //ontouch
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: after navigation in the doc , i can't get the OnTouch event ... :s

Comment: browser.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
   
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    switch (event.getAction()) { 
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
    {
     afficherButtons();
     SessionVar.getInstance().setAfficherNextHTML(false);
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
    {
     afficherButtons();
     SessionVar.getInstance().setAfficherNextHTML(false);
    }
    //ontouch
    break; 
    } 
    return false; 
    
   }
  });

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

    private float mDownPosX;
    private float mDownPosY;
    private float mUpPosX;
    private float mUpPosY;

    private WebView webView;

    private float MOVE_THRESHOLD_DP;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         setContentView(R.layout.webview_layout);

         MOVE_THRESHOLD_DP = 20.0F * act.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
         webView v = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
         v.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) { 
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            this.mDownPosX = event.getX();
            this.mDownPosY = event.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            this.mUpPosX = event.getX();
            this.mUpPosY = event.getY();
            if ((Math.abs(mUpPosX - this.mDownPosX) < MOVE_THRESHOLD_DP) && (Math.abs(mUpPosY - this.mDownPosY) < MOVE_THRESHOLD_DP)) {
                //your click code here
            }

        break; 
        }
        return false; 
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

WebView has the only onTouchListener, not onClickListener but, you can create your own custom ClickListener with help of TouchListener, so, I have created one CustomTouchListener for webView as below,

```
public class WebViewTouchClickListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private static int MAX_CLICK_DURATION = 200;
    private static int MAX_CLICK_DISTANCE = 15;
    private long pressStartTime = 0;
    private float pressedX = 0;
    private float pressedY = 0;
    private boolean stayedWithinClickDistance = false;
    private Context context;
    private TouchClickCallBack touchClickCallBack;


    public WebViewTouchClickListener(Context context, TouchClickCallBack callback) {
        this.context = context;
        this.touchClickCallBack = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                pressStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                pressedX = motionEvent.getX();
                pressedY = motionEvent.getY();
                stayedWithinClickDistance = true;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (stayedWithinClickDistance && distance(pressedX, pressedY, motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY()) > MAX_CLICK_DISTANCE) {
                    stayedWithinClickDistance = false;
                }
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                long pressDuration = System.currentTimeMillis() - pressStartTime;
                if (pressDuration < MAX_CLICK_DURATION && stayedWithinClickDistance) {
                    touchClickCallBack.isClicked();
                }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private float distance(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
        double dx = x1 - x2;
        double dy = y1 - y2;
        double distanceInPx = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        double distanceInDp = distanceInPx / context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        return (float) distanceInDp;
    }

    interface TouchClickCallBack {
        void isClicked();  //This interface method will give callback in activity or fragment were we want to use
    }
}
```

Then in activity implement isClicked() method to open data and pass values as below

```
webView.setOnTouchListener(new WebViewTouchClickListener(context, new WebViewTouchClickListener.TouchClickCallBack {
    @Override                 
    void isClicked() {
                        //TODO: implement the method for doing the stuff based on web view click.
                }))
```

Answer (score -1):

As per my knowledge you cannot get webview click listener. You can use its onTouchListener.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5125620/1401138) elaborates in details how to handle a situation like this

Hope this will be help.