# OnClickListener for the screen layout webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, onclicklistener

I want to get the click event when the user `onClickListener` by clicking on the screen. I have a layout as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout_content">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried to do this by the layout Relative setOnClickListener:

```
RelativeLayout layoutContent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_content);
layoutContent.setOnClickListenner(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ......
    }
});
```

I can get good click event until webview finished loading, I can not get any more clicklistener. So does anyone have any suggestions for me to be able to get onClicklistener after webview loaded?

Comment: sorry, why do you need an onClick event on a webview? I can't imagine a use case.. Btw, have you tried setting that onclick listener on a WebView itself?

Comment: because I need to show and hide a menu when clicking on the screen

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116909/how-i-can-get-onclick-event-on-webview-in-android) answer,

> WebView doesn't seem to send click events to an OnClickListener

For this you need to implement the `onTouchListener` event.

```
public class WebViewClicker extends Activity implements OnTouchListener, Handler.Callback {

private static final int CLICK_ON_WEBVIEW = 1;
private static final int CLICK_ON_URL = 2;

private final Handler handler = new Handler(this);

private WebView webView;
private WebViewClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.web_view_clicker);

    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
    webView.setOnTouchListener(this);

    client = new WebViewClient(){ 
        @Override public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) { 
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(CLICK_ON_URL);
            return false;
        } 
    }; 

    webView.setWebViewClient(client);
    webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.web && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(CLICK_ON_WEBVIEW, 500);
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
    if (msg.what == CLICK_ON_URL){
        handler.removeMessages(CLICK_ON_WEBVIEW);
        return true;
    }
    if (msg.what == CLICK_ON_WEBVIEW){
        Toast.makeText(this, "WebView clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: sry but I need to show and hide a menu when clicking on the screen. if using touch will be confused with the scroll action webview.

Comment: @PhanSinh: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116909/how-i-can-get-onclick-event-on-webview-in-android (replace ACTION_DOWN with ACTION_UP).

Answer (score 0):

```
webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                Intent intent;
                ActivityModel activityModel = new ActivityModel();
                activityModel.setServerId(activityId);
                if (action.equals("discussion")) {
                    intent = new Intent(BannerPopUp.this, DiscussionActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("activityModel", activityModel);
                } else {
                    intent = new Intent(BannerPopUp.this, DisplayActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.MODEL_ACTIVITY, activityModel);
                    if (action.equals("join")) {
                        intent.putExtra(Constants.ACTION, "join");
                    }
                }
                if (!isAppRunning) {
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                }
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return false;`
            }
        });
```