# Open Navigation Drawer on HTML button click

Tags: android, android-webview, navigation-drawer

I have a normal code for opening Navigation Drawer. I want to open the same Navigation Drawer when an HTML button is clicked in `WebView`. I can have a `Toast` or any other simple functions on HTML button click using `WebAppInterface`. But how to open Drawer in this case?

HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidDialog() {
        Luke.showDialog();
    }
</script>

</head>

<body>

<h1>My Web Page</h1>

<p id="demo">Second Page</p>

<button type="button"  onClick="showAndroidDialog()">OK</button>


</body>
</html>
```

RiverFragment.java

```java
public class RiverFragment extends Fragment{


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Retrieving the currently selected item number
        int position = getArguments().getInt("position");

        // List of rivers
        String[] rivers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.rivers);

        // Creating view correspoding to the fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

        // Getting reference to the TextView of the Fragment
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_content);

        // Setting currently selected river name in the TextView
        tv.setText(rivers[position]);       

        // Updating the action bar title
        getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(rivers[position]);

        return v;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Within which the entire activity is enclosed
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    // ListView represents Navigation Drawer
    ListView mDrawerList;

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle indicates the presence of Navigation Drawer in the action bar
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;    

    // Title of the action bar
    String mTitle="";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mTitle = (String) getTitle();       


        // Getting reference to the DrawerLayout
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);


        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);

        // Getting reference to the ActionBarDrawerToggle
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(  this, 
                                                    mDrawerLayout, 
                                                    R.drawable.ic_drawer, 
                                                    R.string.drawer_open,
                                                    R.string.drawer_close){

            /** Called when drawer is closed */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();

            }

            /** Called when a drawer is opened */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle("Select a river");
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

        };

        // Setting DrawerToggle on DrawerLayout
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        // Creating an ArrayAdapter to add items to the listview mDrawerList
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getBaseContext(), 
                    R.layout.drawer_list_item  , 
                    getResources().getStringArray(R.array.rivers) 
                );

        // Setting the adapter on mDrawerList
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Enabling Home button
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // Enabling Up navigation
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // Setting item click listener for the listview mDrawerList
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                            View view,
                            int position,
                            long id) {          

                // Getting an array of rivers
                String[] rivers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.rivers);

                //Currently selected river
                mTitle = rivers[position];              


                // Creating a fragment object
                RiverFragment rFragment = new RiverFragment();

                // Creating a Bundle object
                Bundle data = new Bundle();

                // Setting the index of the currently selected item of mDrawerList
                data.putInt("position", position);

                // Setting the position to the fragment
                rFragment.setArguments(data);

                // Getting reference to the FragmentManager
                FragmentManager fragmentManager  = getFragmentManager();

                // Creating a fragment transaction
                FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

                // Adding a fragment to the fragment transaction
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, rFragment);

                // Committing the transaction
                ft.commit();

                // Closing the drawer
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);             

            }
        }); 
    }


     @Override
     protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);         
         mDrawerToggle.syncState(); 
     }

    /** Handling the touch event of app icon */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {     
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
          return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    /** Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);

        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your webview???

Comment: @Prasad. The above code is for usual navigation drawer so no webview. I want to know how to apply this same navigation if I'm clicking the HTML button instead of the usual drawer icon.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5125620/2247689). I guess using an `onTouchListener()` and a `View` id to intercept a call to the specific button on the `WebView` you could do a `drawerLayout.openDrawer()`.

Comment: actually I can intercept any HTML button click using:
public class WebAppInterface {
     Context mContext;

     /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
     WebAppInterface(Context c) {
         mContext = c;
     }

     /** Show a toast from the web page */
     @JavascriptInterface
     public void showDialog() {
         
      //Toast.makeText(mContext, "toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      
      
      
     }
 }

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same functionality by the interface itself

```
JavaScriptInterface jsInterface = new JavaScriptInterface();
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "Android");
```

Interface class will be:

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {

    public void openDrawer(){
        yourdrawerlayout.open(Gravity.LEFT);
    }
}
```

You need call this `openDrawer` method from html like below

```
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    Android.openDrawer();
});
```

Comment: with this code  a have the next error:Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: Most probably that error will come while we access the UI in worker thread. Generally we need to access the UI in only UI thread i.e. main thread. @moynardos

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `showAndroidDialog()` method on Button click in your HTML code.

`Luke.showDialog();` to interact with android view components.

So you have to call `showDialog()` method in your `JavascriptInterface` to open drawer progrmatically

You can add `JavascriptInterface` like this:

```
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Luke");
```

Your WebAppInterface should be like this:

```
 public class WebAppInterface {
        Context mContext;

        /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
        WebAppInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface   // must be added for API 17 or higher
        public void showDialog() {
         mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT); // open navigation drawer
        }
 }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I will check this and get back to you.

Comment: Just one doubt, activity_main.xml has webview. How can I add another layout for navigation drawer in MainActivity.java? something like R.layout.nav?

Comment: The above code is not working for HTML button but working for Android Button