# react-native Android Webview trigger clicks

Tags: android, ios, webview, react-native

I'm trying to trigger clicks on `WebViews` and want to open them for example in a new `WebView` to make a route flow. In `iOS` I can call the method `onShouldStartLoadWithRequest` and look at the event like this:

```
onShouldStartLoadWithRequest(e) 
{ 
  if(e.navigationType === "click") 
  { 
  }     
}
```

On Android this function doesn't exists. Does someone know how to do something like this? Maybe you handle this in an other way but I really don't have a plan on this. Thanks for any advice

Comment: Do you want to take a click event out from webview to android system ?

Comment: I have a link in the webview and as soon as the link is clicked I want react-native to handle this click and tell my which link is clicked. Then I can either let the Webview load the new link or open a new View for example

Comment: Probably this link will help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116909/how-can-i-get-onclick-event-on-webview-in-android

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by routing the [`onNavigationStateChange`](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.26/docs/webview.html#onnavigationstatechange) function (which fires on Android), to my implementation of `onShouldStartLoadingWithRequest`:

```
onNavigationStateChange (req) {
  if (Platform.OS !== 'ios') {
    this.onShouldStartLoadWithRequest(req)
  }
}
```

And:

```
onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange}
```

In this instance `req` contains the `navigationType` property. Remember to include `Platform` from `react-native`.

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I don't have a navigationType in the req am I missing something?