# How To Detect Redirects in Android Web view

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, url, webview

After several redirects the url finally ends up in Webform How can i Exit from the webview ? 
Is There a way i can detect Html element in webview like button in the page. I cannot use Javascript here since i don't own the sites

```
public class ProductionWebView extends Activity{


    private WebView webView;
    String url ="https://www.google.lk/?gws_rd=ssl";



    @SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface")
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.production_webview);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.loadUrl(url);

        //ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object()
        {
          public void performClick()
          {
              // Deal with a click on the OK button
          }
        }, "Next");
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object()
        {

          public void performClick()
          {

          }
        }, "Authorize");        

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a webClient and implement shouldOverrideUrlLoading to intercept all the urls before the WebView loads them.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {

       // Here put your code to exit

       // return true; //This indicates WebView to NOT load the url;
       // return false; //Allow WebView to load url
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank You for your Reply.
If the web view have several redirects how can you track them with this code? I tried the code but it is not even loading the 1 st url now

Comment: @SheshanGamage Did you return false ?

Comment: I used this block
`
   webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


      @Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
    
    if(webView.getUrl().contains("code")){
     return true;
    }
    else{
     return false;
    }

      }
  });
 }
`
but its not loading now its giving me false and doesn't load anything

Comment: @SheshanGamage You are already getting Url as parameter. Try using that..

Comment: The problem is that the method dosent iterate :(
it just works for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manipulate the URL then override this:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url){
       view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
       return true;
}
```

[[WebViewClient Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html)]

Comment: please check link mentioned in my answer@Sheshan Gamage

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5125620/2826147 it is i think what you needed.@Sheshan Gamage

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a method like this

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
        // do your action here
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false; // then it is not handled by default action
   }
});
```

Comment: If the web view have several redirects how can you track them with this code?
I tried but it is not even loading the 1 st url now

Comment: You can put log in shouldOverrideUrlLoading method to get all the redirects info