# On Click Listeners in MathView

Tags: android, android-studio

How can I put click listeners on MathView, I Usually do this using a Button or TextView but now I want to do it using MathView. My code is below but is not working when I click it, it does not do anything. Is there anything wrong or missing code?

**XML**

```
<io.github.kexanie.library.MathView
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:onClick="ClickMe"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/answerBtn_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/answerBtn_height"
    auto:engine="MathJax"
    auto:text="Click Me"
    android:focusable="true" />
```

**Java.class**

```
public void ClickMe(View view) {
    Intent intent =  new Intent(MainActivity.this, Class2.class);
    startActivity(intent);    }
```

I tried also to use the ID and call the Id in java but it still does nothing, so i want it to open a new activity, is there anything missing on my code?

Comment: of course it wont work , `android:onClick="ClickMe"` in `xml` you have method name `ClickMe` and in `java` `Mateu`

Comment: sorry can you check again my code Abdul Kawee, i have corrected it, it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

Since the "MathView" is a actually a webview you can't put a click listener on it.
Here is a solution which might work for you 
[How can I get onclick event on webview in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116909/how-can-i-get-onclick-event-on-webview-in-android/5125620#5125620)