# Getting click event from the webview in android

Tags: android

I am using webView and I want to get the click event of the button on the webview in my app and want to perform operation from my side . But I am unable to get the click event. I have tried many methods searched from google by enabling the javascript from the webview but no any method worked. Please help
Thanks in advance.

I am using this code where valid is the name of the button in the HTML file.

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object() {

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void performClick() {

            GeneralFunctions.showToast(HomeActivity.this, "clicked");
        }
    }, "valid");
```

Comment: Is the webpage fix or dynamic ?

Comment: Go for below link it helps you alot . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116909/how-can-i-get-onclick-event-on-webview-in-android

Comment: I am passing the url ..@NiravJoshi

Comment: Scroll here https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview till you see -Binding JavaScript code to Android code-

Comment: Thanks for answering @AhmedI.Elsayed. I posted the answer and solved the issue. Please check.

Comment: I saw, check the link for more if you want, anyway mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Here I am describing a code block of click event of webview (JavaScript) you can modify your code like this

```
WebSettings ws = webView.getSettings();
ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object()
{
   @JavascriptInterface           // For API 17+
   public void performClick(String strl)
   {
      stringVariable = strl;
      Toast.makeText (YourActivity.this, stringVariable, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}, "valid");
```

And HTML

```
<button type="button" value="someValue" onclick="valid.performClick(this.value);">Valid</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering @Vijay Pal .. I already used the same code.

Answer (score 1):

So Finally I got the answer. After enabling the Javascript. I have to enable the

```
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

So that performClick can work.The correct code is;

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true); // This line will be added
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.example.com/");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object(){
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void performClick(String val){

            GeneralFunctions.showToast(HomeActivity.this,val+"clicked");
        }
    },"ok");
```

Answer (score 0):

**100% working example - I had to listen a event from webview in android app. The below event was fired from Website in webview (iFrame).**

```
  window.addEventListener('event_name_goes_here', function (response) {
        if (response.data.status === 200) {
            console.log(response.data.message);
        }
});
```

**In Android to listen this event write below code in onPageFinished on webview**

```
 binding.webview.loadUrl(
                        "javascript:(function() {" +
                                "window.addEventListener('event_name_goes_here', function(response) {" +
                                " Android.receiveMessage(JSON.stringify(response.data));});" +
                                "})()"

                )
```

**Write inner class to fetch the event**

```
class JsObject(val context: Context) {
    @JavascriptInterface
    fun receiveMessage(data: String): Boolean {
        Log.e("data_from_web", data)
        Toast.makeText(context,data.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        return true
    }
```

**Initilize webview like this**

```
 binding.webview.apply {          
        loadUrl(mUrl ?: "")
        settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        settings.setSupportZoom(false)
        settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        addJavascriptInterface(JsObject(requireContext()), "Android")       
    }
```