# (WebView) view.setOnTouchListener not triggered

Tags: java, android

I am having the html file in my asset folder. Now i am trying to access the content with `onTouch` event. The following is my code.I have added two images for the reference.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

```cpp
view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);  // disabling touch events
    }
});
view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

Comment: [I find this for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116909/how-can-i-get-onclick-event-on-webview-in-android) it works to me .

Comment: @orangeai Thanks for the reply. I tried that earlier and it was not working for me. The touch event is happening. I tries this by changing the text's background color. But the problem is i am trying to parse the text to access the tts service. The event is happening, but the text is not getting parsed through `hover_enter`.