# How to get touch event information in android webView?

Tags: android, events, webview

I try to figure out if the user touched the screen and what element he pressed on and gather information about that element, e.g. if the user pressed on a image which is wrapped by a anchor html tag, then I try to figure out the source.

**Background:**

There is a link image on our website which has a relative URL e.g.

```
<a href="/products/product01.html`><img src="/media/images/image01.jpg"></a>
```

However, there is a bug in Android webview, and the webview fails to recognize this as a link. So I need to workaround by listening on everything the user touches, figuring out if it is a link and add the base URL in front of it, if the link starts with a slash `/`.

I tried it like this, but nothing is logged:

```
public class FullscreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private WebView blizzView;
    private Button backButton;
    private String website;

    private View.OnTouchListener handleTouch = new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            Log.i("debug_log", "touch");

            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Log.i("debug_log", "touched down");
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    Log.i("debug_log", "moving: (" + x + ", " + y + ")");
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Log.i("debug_log", "touched up");
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    };
...
```

I filtered for `debug_log` of course

[image]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57146744/android-webview-cant-open-relative-urls-starting-with?noredirect=1#comment100813248_57146744

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5116909/6950238) question and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that the webView has a function called `setOnTouchListener` where I have to add the logic:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Message;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebResourceResponse;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 */
public class FullscreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private WebView webView;
    private Button backButton;
    private String website;

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        website = "https://www.example.com";
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                int x = (int) event.getX();
                int y = (int) event.getY();

                Log.i("debug_log", "moving: (" + x + ", " + y + ")");

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        Log.i("debug_log", "touched down");
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        Log.i("debug_log", "moving: (" + x + ", " + y + ")");
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        Log.i("debug_log", "touched up");
                        break;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

        // URL laden:
        webView.loadUrl(website);
    }

    ...
```