# Is it possible findViewById from WebView?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

How can I get different view in `WebView`

or if web developer can tell me view's id?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webView)
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com")

//        Is it possible?
//        val button1 = webView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button1)
//        val button2 = webView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)
//
//        button1.setOnClickListener { fun1() }
//        button2.setOnClickListener { fun2() }
    }
}
```

Appreciate for any help, thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116909/how-can-i-get-onclick-event-on-webview-in-android

Comment: @PankajKumar It can only get click event but can not get view

Comment: You can not get the view. Is there any specific reason for getting the view?

Comment: Because pm ask if android app can interactive with webview.If can, some page will be webView and android app won't need to make ui.

Comment: It's completely a bad idea and not achievable. Better to make your app in any cross-platform tech. Reading View is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is NOT possible to use `findViewById` for obtaining web-level widgets. It's for framework widgets only. There is no reliable way for handling web-based widgets on Java/Kotlin side in a way you want (just like native ones), but you can use some [JS interfaces](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#BindingJavaScript) for calling click-related methods

Answer (score 0):

**findViewById** is not possible in webview instead of you can use Javascript interface

```
  webview.addJavascriptInterface(new Object()
  {
      @JavascriptInterface
    public void performClick()
    {
        Log.d("LOGIN::", "Clicked");
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login clicked", 
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }, "login");
```